# Gen 2 Azure VM HDD

Tags: windows, azure, azure-image

would anyone know if we can use a standard MBR boot partition when using the UEFI vm.

Does it need to be a GPT partition? We are migrating machines to Azure and we are setting the hard drive size and want to use the standard MBR, without having to tweak the partition to GPT.

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I’ve never tried to migrate servers with MBR but I think you will have trouble booting.

> To boot your PC in UEFI mode, you'll need to use a drive formatted using the GPT drive format.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-8.1-and-8/dn336946(v=win.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

I think you need to actually do a test migration to be sure